# # of DIMMs per channel vs. channel memory mode

Tags: memory, bios, chipset, dell-precision

I have purchased a Dell Precision 5520 laptop with two identical 16 GB DDR4 memory cards installed. The information section in BIOS states that `single channel memory mode` is being used. There is no setting in BIOS to change that to `dual channel`. Resetting to factory settings did not result in switching to `dual channel mode` either. Is this the normal state of things?

Not sure whether this is directly related, but the [chipset information page](https://ark.intel.com/products/98087/Mobile-Intel-CM238-Chipset) says:

`# of DIMMs per channel: 2`

The memory model is: [Crucial 16GB DDR4-2400 SODIMM
CT16G4SFD824A](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct16g4sfd824a)

CPU: Intel Core Xeon E3-1505M v6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every reference I have found to the Dell Precision 5520 says it supports
dual-channel RAM, with one exception : The Dell site and manual say
absolutely nothing about whether the RAM supports it or not.

So if these websites are right, then the RAM you have is wrong.

Is this RAM the original one that came with the laptop?
If you gave us its specification we could say more,
and the exact specification for the laptop itself would also help.

Here are the references I have found :

- https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Precision-5520-UHD.218926.0.html
- https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Precision-5520-E3-1505M-UHD-Workstation-Review.213844.0.html
- http://laptopmedia.com/review/dell-precision-5520-review-the-xps-15-for-professionals/
- https://www.notebookcheck.org/Dell-Precision-5520-UHD.218928.0.html

Comment: I edited the post with precise memory and CPU specifications.

Comment: Did you buy the laptop second hand?  I used the [Crucial Advisor tool](http://www.crucial.com/) and this RAM is not recommend for the laptop, so I have my doubts about this being the original RAM (although this may only mean that your RAM stick is not manufactured any more by Crucial).

Comment: The laptop is new. However, it came with two 8 GB sticks. When I requested 32 GB, they (the distributor) installed this RAM.  For some reason, they did not have original RAM from DELL...

Comment: Could using this RAM damage the computer?

Comment: Well, Crucial is usually cheaper ...  I don't think that using this RAM can cause damage. The computer might be just a tiny bit slower for some operations than it could be. You may keep on using it with no worries.

Comment: Interestingly, another Crucial Advisor tool (http://b2b.orderingmemory.com) does list this memory... It looks like this laptop comes with two different chipsets: CM236 or CM238. I tried to find out which one I have (by using sysinfo, lspci and dmidecode under Ubuntu) without success. I did not notice the chipset model being listed in BIOS either. Any idea?

Comment: I noticed there are different sub-models, which is why I asked for the exact specification for the laptop. You could try the Crucial System Scanner to see what it says - I always found it to be very exact (requires Windows).